# Как убрать Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Помогите разобраться с react-router
есть компонент App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Header/Header'));
const FormLayout = React.lazy(() => import('./Layouts/FormLayout/FormLayout'));
const RegistrationForm = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Forms/RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm'));
const LogonForm = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Forms/LogonForm/LogonForm'));
import './App.css';

const LogonFormLayouted =  <FormLayout children = { <LogonForm /> } />;
const RegistrationFormLayouted = <FormLayout children = { <RegistrationForm /> } />;

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={ LogonForm } />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
};
```

При его рендеринге в консоле warning[image: Warning]

И почему код не работает когда я в Route передаю компонент LogonFormLayouted

Answer (score 2):

В `component` требуется передать объект, а вы передаете в него функцию-обертку. В вашем случае лучше использовать свойство `render`

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={(props) => <LogonForm {...props}/>}
/>
```